# Flexbox bug with .flex-video

Tags: css, html5-video, flexbox

I am currently trying to achieve what I thought would be a simple task:

- A flex row with two *automatically sized* (`flex: 0 0 auto;`) child elements that are centered vertically and horizontally.
- The children themselves are flex columns.
- Inside one of the child elements, I am wanting to have a fluid YouTube video.

Here is my initial code that I suspected would work:

http://codepen.io/tatemz/pen/dMqKbb

Okay, simple. That works well and I am happy. Now I build my `.flex-video` class:

```
/* Taken from http://foundation.zurb.com/sites */
.flex-video {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

  .flex-video iframe,
  .flex-video object,
  .flex-video embed,
  .flex-video video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .flex-video.widescreen {
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  }

  .flex-video.vimeo {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
```

Now, when we put it all together and nest our `.flex-video` inside of one of our child flex columns, the layout breaks. It would appear that the parent flex column containing the `.flex-video` cannot calculate its dimensions.

http://codepen.io/tatemz/pen/qZMKdz

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLNedq?editors=1100

```
.child {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

I've just changed your flex basis to be `50%` instead of `auto`, and I've moved the `max-width` declaration up a level.

Though, when you say "automatically sized", it's not clear what size you're referring to. Do you want it to start out at the size from the `width` and `height` attributes and then adjust to fit the container? If so then setting the flex grow/shrink properties to `0` isn't going to work.

If you clarify what exactly you're hoping to achieve, it'll be easier for someone to answer your question.